# Code that splits an array and counts repetitions

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

The following code nearly works but for some reason the first value in the array printed is also the last value and also the first value of the next set of data that is printed. I know that might sound confusing.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 288

int nThArrayPrint(double prev, int count, int i, double *array) {
int j = MAX*i;
for (i = j; i <(j+MAX); i++) {
    if (array[i] == prev) {
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("%.4lf= %d\t", prev, count);
        prev = array[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}
return count;
```

}

```
int main()
{
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\niall\\Desktop\\question2.txt", "r");
double array[MAX * 5]; // Initializes array to all 0.0s
int i, x, j, count;
double prev = 0;

if (fp != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX * 5; i++) { //Load values from file into an array
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &array[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    prev = array[0]; // initialize
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        count = 1;
        printf("\tNumber of times each value is repeated for the %dth set of values\n\n", i+1);
        count = nThArrayPrint(prev, count, i, array);
        prev = array[MAX*i];
         printf("%.4lf= %d\n\n", prev, count);
    }
} else {
    printf("There was a probem opening the file.");
}
}
```

Comment: `double array[MAX * 5];// Initializes array to all 0.0s`... how? isn't `array` in `auto` storage?

Comment: Sorry i did not get you.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. What is wrong with declaring the array at MAX*5. The original file stores 1440 elements which i need to split into 5 and print the repetition of each element in each group

Comment: nothing wrong with defining the array. Wrong is your assumption that it will get _initialized to 0.0_, it won't. You've to do that explicitly, is you want. Also, it's advisable to check the return value of `fscanf()` to check the success.

Answer (score 0):

modify the below segment of the code

```
prev = array[0]; // initialize
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    count = 1;
    printf("\tNumber of times each value is repeated for the %dth set of values\n\n", i+1);
    count = nThArrayPrint(prev, count, i, array);
    prev = array[MAX*i];
     printf("%.4lf= %d\n\n", prev, count);
}
```

into

```
count = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("\tNumber of times each value is repeated for the %dth set of values\n\n", i+1);
    for (j = i*MAX; j < (i*MAX)+MAX; j++) {
        if (array[j] == array[j+1]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            printf("%.4lf= %d\n", array[j], count);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    if(count > 1){
        printf("%.4lf= %d\n", array[j], count-1);
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

Tested with below input with MAX as 9

```
12 12 12 12 12 1 1 1 1 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 62 2.2 2.2 2.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 22 22 22 22 22 1 22 22 22 22
```

output:

```
    Number of times each value is repeated for the 1th set of values

12.0000= 5
1.0000= 4
    Number of times each value is repeated for the 2th set of values

4.0000= 1
5.0000= 2
6.0000= 1
7.0000= 1
8.0000= 1
9.0000= 1
3.0000= 2
    Number of times each value is repeated for the 3th set of values

3.0000= 1
2.0000= 3
1.0000= 5
    Number of times each value is repeated for the 4th set of values

1.0000= 1
6.0000= 1
62.0000= 1
2.2000= 3
3.2000= 3
    Number of times each value is repeated for the 5th set of values

3.2000= 1
22.0000= 5
1.0000= 1
22.0000= 2
```